# Summer 18 - navigateToURL Issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, summer-18

i got another problem with the summer18 release regarding the URL changes.

I use a visualforcepage to render a pdf that is liked to a button on a lightning component. The redirection works this way:

```
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
  urlEvent.setParams({
   "url": "/apex/visualforcePageName?quoteID=" + quoteId
  });
  urlEvent.fire();
```

Ive no problem in production, but get this error message in my summer18 sandbox:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided ('https://XYZ--devnov16.lightning.force.com') does not match
>   the recipient window's origin
>   ('https://XYZ--devnov16--c.visualforce.com'). postMessage @
>   iframeHelper.js:2

As descripted in the SF FAQ there should be no issues like that.

> What about logic that creates URLs in the old format?
>
> Logic that create URLs in the old format like bookmarks, email
>   templates, and force:navigateToURL in Lightning components will
>   continue to work.

Can anybody confirm and provide a workaround?

Thank u!

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but did you try adding the `https://XYZ--devnov16--c.visualforce.com` in CORS as a workaround?

Comment: Thank u for this idea! Unfortunally that workaround doesnt solve the problem.